# Change property of "super/base" style wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, inheritance, styles, basedon

I am creating a base style. I am using inheritance to implement my base style. I know how to add properties on my derived class but I don't know how to just change a property. Let me give you an example:

let say I have this base style:

```
        <!-- SrollViewer ScrollBar Repeat Buttons (at each end) -->
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border
                        Name="Border"
                        Margin="1"
                        CornerRadius="2"
                        Background="WhiteSmoke"          
                        BorderThickness="1">
                        <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="/FilesPro;component/Images/scrollArrow.png" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="52" >
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="40"/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
                        <!--
                        <Path
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
                            Data="{Binding Path=Content,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
                        </Path>
                        -->
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

I would like to create a new style that has the same properties as ScrollBarLineButton but with the image transfrom scaleY=1 instead of -1.

when I do:

```
        <Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButtonVerticalUp" BasedOn="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border>                            
                        <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="/FilesPro;component/Images/scrollArrow.png" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="52" >
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" />
                                     ....
                                     ...
```

border no longer has its base style margin, Background color etc.. How could I inherit from the style and just change one property. I know I can copy paste but I will change this a lot and it is convenient that if I change it in one place it changes in all the other places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a `DynamicResource` reference to do something like this, here's an example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyleA" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBrush" Color="Yellow" />
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
                            <ContentPresenter TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource TextBrush}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyleB" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyleA}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBrush" Color="Blue" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleA}" Content="Lorem Ipsum" />
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleB}" Content="Lorem Ipsum" />
</StackPanel>
```

In `StyleB` the `TextBrush` is overridden which causes the template to change as well since it references this resource.